# AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin not working with CupertinoSwitch

Tags: flutter, dart

I have page where build ListView with CupertinoSwitch.

```
    class NewsPageRegistr extends StatefulWidget {
  NewsPageRegistr({Key key, this.model}) : super(key: key);
  RegistrationModel model;
  @override
  _NewsPageRegistrState createState() => _NewsPageRegistrState();
}

class _NewsPageRegistrState extends State<NewsPageRegistr>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<NewsPageRegistr> {
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  var responseV;
  List<DigitalNews> digitalNews = [];
  @override
  void dispose() {
    
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    fitchData();
    super.initState();
  }


  fitchData() async {
    responseV = await apiRegistrationDataList(DropMenuMode.news);
    for (var values in responseV) {
      digitalNews.add(DigitalNews.fromJson(values));
    }
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: SafeArea(
        minimum: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 0, 25, 0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              width: 400,
              height: 85,
              child: Text(
                "Ich möchte folgende Newsletter abonnieren",
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                style: GeneralStyles.titleStyle,
              ),
            ),
            ListView.builder(
                //padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: digitalNews.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return CheckWidget(
                    title: digitalNews[index].displayName,
                    subtitle: digitalNews[index].displayDescription,
                    registrationName: digitalNews[index].name,
                    index: index,
                    model: widget.model,
                  );
                }),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        OutlinedButton(
                            style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                              backgroundColor: GeneralStyles.petrolColor,
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {});
                              widget.model.setCurrentPage(2);

                            },
                            child: const Text(
                              "Weiter",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                  fontFamily: 'FiraSans'),
                            )),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

I use AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin but it not working when i jump to next page (on PageView).
I add AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin on main widget when call PageView, add to CheckWidget and to NewsPageRegistr widget but it not working. when i jump to other page on PageView List NewsPageRegistr state is dispose.
Code of widget:

```
class CheckWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  RegistrationModel model;
  bool checker = false;
  final Function(String) onChanged;
  final String title;
  final String subtitle;
  final String registrationName;
  final int index;

  CheckWidget({Key key, this.onChanged, this.title, this.subtitle, this.registrationName, this.index,this.model}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CheckWidget> createState() => _CheckWidgetState();
}

class _CheckWidgetState extends State<CheckWidget> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return  Container(
      child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Transform.scale(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              scale: 0.8,
              child: CupertinoSwitch(
                value: widget.checker,
                activeColor: GeneralStyles.petrolColor,
                onChanged: (bool value) {
                  setState(() {
                    widget.checker = value;
                    if(value == true) {
                    widget.model.newsPapers[widget.index] = widget.registrationName;
                    }else {
                      widget.model.newsPapers[widget.index] = '';
                    }
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: GestureDetector(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(widget.title.replaceFirst("Newsletter", "").trim(), style:TextStyle(
                      color: GeneralStyles.blackColor,
                      fontSize: 15,
                      fontFamily: 'FiraSans',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    )),
                    Text(widget.subtitle, style:TextStyle(
                      color: GeneralStyles.blackColor,
                      fontSize: 13,
                      fontFamily: 'FiraSans',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                    )),
                  ],
                ),
                onTap: (){
                  setState(() {

                    if(widget.checker == false) {
                      widget.checker = true;
                     widget.model.newsPapers[widget.index] = widget.registrationName;
                    }else {
                      widget.checker = false;
                      widget.model.newsPapers[widget.index] = '';
                    }
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          ]
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you already tried to add AutomaticKeepAliveMixin to CheckWidget ?

Comment: @CesarelsHere, yes

Comment: Maybe post a complete example ready to be started so I can try to reproduce the problem.